# Updating an excel request in js

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, exceljs

I would try to update a request in an excel file but using js. I have an excel file that contains data from a calendar and i update the data by taking the date of today being the first cell.

I already try to import the file with an input, already tried the library exceljs.

I dont know how to do.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(async function(data) {    
      // console.log(data);
      // I tried this too :
      const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
      await workbook.xlsx.read(stream);
      await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("data.xlsx");
      console.log(workbook);
      
      
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="input">
<table id="tbl-data"></table>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.